# Sonarqube Rule: Identifying multiple method calls in one line

Tags: java, sonarqube, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to implement a custom SonarQube-Rule that identifies Java stream API usage and detects a violation, when more than one method is called in the same codeline, after the `.stream` call is made.

Example:

```
// BAD CODE:
strings.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 2).sorted()
.map(s -> s.substring(0, 2)).collect(Collectors.toList());

// GOOD CODE:
strings.stream()
.filter(s -> s.length() > 2)
.sorted()
.map(s -> s.substring(0, 2))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've already identified the different method calls through a MethodInvocationTree visitor, but how am I able to identify them as stream() method calls, telling them apart from all other method calls in my code? Espacially since my parameter method calls are also identified as an AST MethodInvocationTree.

Is there maybe a SonarQube helper class, that helps me go deeper into the AST or lets me pick out the exact parts of the AST I need, like PMD's `node.getFirstChildOfType(ASTTree.class)`?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question, the SonarJava API does not provide any way to filter children directly from the AST by their tree kind. It has to be done during visit.

Now, there might be several ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but you will most certainly needs to work with both syntax and semantic API. Note that this rule may require quite a lot of work to cover all the cases.

I would suggest you to look at the [`methodSelect`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.3.0.13828/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/tree/MemberSelectExpressionTree.java#L42) tree of the `MethodInvocationTree`, and from there check if first it's a [`MemberSelectExpressionTree`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.3.0.13828/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/tree/MemberSelectExpressionTree.java#L42), get the identifier, and then again the `MethodInvocationTree` from the selected member. By looping on it till you reach something which is not a method invocation, or directly an identifier, you should collect all the method invocations. Now, there is the question of how to be sure it's a method from `java.util.stream.Stream`.

Once collected, for each method invocation of the chain, you can then use the semantic API to access the [`symbol()`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.3.0.13828/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/tree/MethodInvocationTree.java#L52) corresponding to the invoked method. If the methods are correctly resolved by the semantic engine (bytecode is provided for analysis, type inference correctly computed by the engine, symbol not flagged as being [`unknown`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.3.0.13828/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/semantic/Symbol.java#L88)), you should be able to verify the type of the *owner* of the method. For all these methods, the owner should be `java.util.stream.Stream`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the line number of the specific MethodInvocationTree? So far I was only able to get the line() of the first or last Token..

Comment: You can take the last token of the `methodInvocationTree`'s `methodSelect()` for that. It should give you the token corresponding to the `IdentifierTree` of the method.

Comment: I've got the custom rule working out well with the suggestions you gave me, thank you very much for that!  Purely out of interest: it seems like the `MethodInvocationTree` visitor starts at the back of my string of method calls, first returning `.collect()` then `.map()` and so forth.. Is it possible to first return the `.stream()` method, so I can specify which expressions to check, instead of going through the whole thing and realizing it's not the code I was looking for?

Comment: @Z.Hunter that's because of the way the syntax tree is built. Basically, your last method invocation includes the prior invocations. There is no easy way in the API to do that.